# Typescript with an external library using es6 modules

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to use Typescript with libraries that are not modules and are not typescript such as PixiJS and SortableJS. What would be the best way to do this using es6 modules? I would prefer not to use something like webpacker.

Comment: According to the docs of sortable, you should be able to import it just like this: `import Sortable from 'sortablejs';`

Comment: If I do that Typescript gives me "Cannot find module"

Comment: Did you install it though?

Comment: Install? If you mean load it with a script tag then yes

Comment: That might be the problem - you should use `npm` to install it (docs: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#getting-started)
As soon as you use it via script tag it's not a proper module.

Comment: Yes but then how to I load it without using something like webpacker?

Comment: How do you run your typescript code without anything that transpiles it? How does your main file (app.ts or something like that) look?

Comment: I use PHPStorm's built in compiler, it compile every file separately. My main file is only the import and a console.log(Sortable)

Comment: Hmm just try to import it...
Or otherwise: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-a-typescript-project-67b427114884/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like

```
import * as Pixie from 'pixie.js'
```

Then you could use it like

```
// Not familiar with what the libraries do or what they are
Pixie.doSomething or const pixie = new Pixie()
```

As i am not familiar with the libraries you mentioned obviously i may have not quoted the correct path but you get the idea. When i use loadsh in my ts projects without webpack but pure ts this works `import * as _ from 'loadsh`

Be aware tho! If u are not using webpack or something similar when u conpile with tsc it will bundle any library u import into the .js file every time u import it that means your files will be of substuntial size!

Webpack helps you create all those libraries into external single bundles where all your .js files will receive them from that single bundle thus minimzing your file size.

Comment: Hmmm so Typescript will need to be configured to compile to a single file?

Comment: As far as i am aware it is impossible with just the Typescript compiler to do that. That being said if its not for an industrial project but rather a personal thing this wont really be an issue :). But i do suggest looking at webpack or browserify if this is a behaviour you are after.

Comment: No it's exactly what I don't want, I want to use as few dependencies as possible because I don't like having too many compilers and stuff stacked on top of eachother. I'm also planning to use it with php so I don't want to use the node webserver that helps with developing in webpack and such.

Comment: Hi Apologies for the late replay on this but what u are looking for is completely out of the context of your question, however, the short answer to what you are looking for it is very simple to integrate PHP and webpack / node. There is no need to use a node webserver rather than simply compile your .ts code using webpack in your build process since you will be deploying your php code somewhere and that has to go through a build / deploy process regardless.

Comment: No worries, I don't expect many replies in the first place. Is there any program that places the libraries in places where I can access them with Typescript? I think that would be the best solution, I'd only need to run it every time I change something with npm.

Comment: I think you need to read up on Typescript and NPM alongside with webpack and how to connect them with PHP. What you describe is exactly what npm does, and as i've mentioned before npm and node can be easily and infact are 90% of them time integrated with PHP. PHP in itself is a server side language Typescript is a frontend.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to take a closer look at it to be sure but I was under the impression that it just compiled to a single bundled file? The main problem I have is that I don't want to compile each time I edit something.